# Android facebook-connect-logout method is not working

Tags: android, facebook

Sir this method i am using but this is not working

```
public void logoutFromFacebook() 
{
    mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
            if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                // User successfully Logged out
            }
        }
```

Comment: public void logoutFromFacebook() 
 {
     mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
         @Override
         public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
             Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
             if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                 // User successfully Logged out
             }
         }

Comment: What error it showing, can you please post the error?

Comment: can you show your code detail?

Comment: {"error_code","error_msg":"Unknown method","request_args":[{"key":"access_token","value":"CAAUbnNAQaNUBAFJlZBHuvmbXbNDytWDZCUQY7zs3fYwXJaA53LNvGRnvP09ni8PiJTo6L3L9IC0w4YdZB7B4WuyfGsWve8RxsT7gRQzqvXsvg8E9vriLCTAflDEHjz8LluDh7L46cOXkZBFe02U97bZB71v5NixZBw0HlitxMeZA3oPfn98QS6horCaDKvUSRoZD"}

Comment: Sir I am Following This Tutorial  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to kill authentication cookies. Try-`facebook.logout(getApplicationContext());`